# how to use actual file name matched by pattern in gulp-template

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp

I have my project structure like this:

```
./
 -index.html
 -js/
    -app.js
    -home/
         -home.js
```

I wanted to match all javascript files inside `js` folder and use them in index file. So, in my `gulpfile.js` is used like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
template = require('gulp-template');

var js = ['js/**/*.js'];

gulp.task('default', function() {
return gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(template({
            scripts: js,
            name: 'index',
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

index.html

```
<%= name %>
<!-- compiled JavaScript --><% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= file %>"></script><% }); %>
```

Which renders index.html like this:

```
<!-- compiled JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/**/*.js"></script>
```

Which obviously not going to work. So how can I display actual file names in place of pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glob pattern needs to be expanded into an array of actual filepaths. This is usually handled for you by `gulp.src`.

You can use [`globby`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby) to expand the pattern like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var template = require('gulp-template');
var globby = require('globby'); // npm install --save-dev globby

var js = globby.sync(['js/**/*.js']);

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(template({
            scripts: js,
            name: 'index',
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```